# Error porting Odoo v8 module to Odoo v12 when i try to update the current invoice i'm adding a debit note from wizard form

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I'm porting odoo v8 module to odoo v12, when i try to update the current invoice adding a debit note.

This is my code:

```
2019-08-01 19:14:42,390 6827 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,390 6827 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /home/desarrollo/.odoorc 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,391 6827 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/desarrollo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/12.0', '/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/addons', '/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/custom/l10n-ve', '/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/addons'] 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,391 6827 INFO ? odoo: database: desarrollo@default:default 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,511 6827 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,603 6827 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.models.res_currency: The num2words python library is not installed, amount-to-text features won't be fully available. 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,638 6827 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on desarrollo-Inspiron-3542:8069 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,651 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,673 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.02s, 0 queries 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,798 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: updating modules list 
2019-08-01 19:14:42,801 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on [] to user __system__ #1 via n/a 
2019-08-01 19:14:43,877 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_upgrade on ['l10n_vzla_dcnote'] to user __system__ #1 via n/a 
2019-08-01 19:14:43,878 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.update_list on ['l10n_vzla_dcnote'] to user __system__ #1 via n/a 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,407 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.addons.base.models.ir_module: ALLOW access to module.button_install on [] to user __system__ #1 via n/a 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,461 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: loading 39 modules... 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,645 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.addons.sms.wizard.send_sms: The `phonenumbers` Python module is not available. Phone number validation will be skipped. Try `pip3 install phonenumbers` to install it. 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,745 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_partnerledger has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,745 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_generalledger has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,745 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_trialbalance has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,745 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_tax has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,746 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_agedpartnerbalance has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,746 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_journal has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:44,746 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.models: The model report.accounting_pdf_reports.report_financial has no _description 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,217 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceDebit._get_journal in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_debit 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,217 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceDebit._get_period in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_debit 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,217 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceDebit._get_orig in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_debit 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,218 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent._get_partner in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,218 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.fields_view_get in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,218 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.default_get in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,218 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.get_window in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.check_sure in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.check_recursion in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.check_grandfather in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.action_assigned in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.action_unlink in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.action_modify in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,219 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.api: Deprecated method AccountInvoiceParent.invoice_operation in module odoo.addons.l10n_vzla_dcnote.wizard.account_invoice_parent 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,287 6827 WARNING l10n_three odoo.fields: Field account.invoice.debit.period with unknown comodel_name 'account.period' 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,367 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.registry: module l10n_vzla_dcnote: creating or updating database tables 
2019-08-01 19:14:45,577 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: loading l10n_vzla_dcnote/account_invoice_view.xml 
2019-08-01 19:14:46,076 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: loading l10n_vzla_dcnote/wizard/account_invoice_debit_view.xml 
2019-08-01 19:14:46,130 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: loading l10n_vzla_dcnote/wizard/account_invoice_parent_view.xml 
2019-08-01 19:14:46,176 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: Module l10n_vzla_dcnote: loading demo 
2019-08-01 19:14:46,291 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: 39 modules loaded in 1.83s, 14 queries 
2019-08-01 19:14:46,818 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.registry: verifying fields for every extended model 
2019-08-01 19:14:47,187 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded. 
2019-08-01 19:14:54,830 6827 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
2019-08-01 19:14:54,838 6827 INFO l10n_three odoo.addons.base.models.ir_http: Generating routing map 
2019-08-01 19:14:54,991 6827 ERROR l10n_three odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 654, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 312, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 696, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 344, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 337, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 939, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/http.py", line 517, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 749, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/odoo-12.0/odoo/api.py", line 736, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/custom/l10n-ve/l10n_vzla_dcnote/wizard/account_invoice_debit.py", line 218, in invoice_debit
    return self.compute_debit()
  File "/home/desarrollo/Documentos/odoo-12/custom/l10n-ve/l10n_vzla_dcnote/wizard/account_invoice_debit.py", line 207, in compute_debit
    result = mod_obj.get_object_reference(self,'account', xml_id)
TypeError: get_object_reference() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

This bellow is the code of my account_invoice_debit.py

```
# coding: utf-8
import time

from odoo import api, fields, models, _
from odoo.tools.translate import _

class AccountInvoiceDebit(models.TransientModel):

    """Debits Note from Invoice"""

    _name = "account.invoice.debit"
    _description = "Invoice Debit Note"

    date = fields.Date('Operation date',
                        help='This date will be used as the invoice date '
                                'for Refund Invoice and Period will be '
                                'chosen accordingly!')
    period = fields.Many2one('account.period', 'Force period')
    journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal',
                                    'Refund Journal',
                                    help='You can select here the journal '
                                        'to use for the refund invoice '
                                        'that will be created. If you '
                                        'leave that field empty, it will '
                                        'use the same journal as the '
                                        'current invoice.')
    description = fields.Char('Description', size=128, required=True)
    comment = fields.Text('Comment', required=True)

    def _get_journal(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        obj_journal = self.pool.get('account.journal')
        user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        inv_type = context.get('type', 'out_invoice')
        company_id = user_obj.browse(
            cr, uid, uid, context=context).company_id.id
        type = (inv_type == 'out_invoice') and 'sale_refund' or \
               (inv_type == 'out_refund') and 'sale' or \
               (inv_type == 'in_invoice') and 'purchase_refund' or \
               (inv_type == 'in_refund') and 'purchase'
        journal = obj_journal.search(cr, uid, [('type', '=', type), (
            'company_id', '=', company_id)], limit=1, context=context)
        return journal and journal[0] or False

    _defaults = {
        'date': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        'journal_id': _get_journal,
    }

    def _get_period(self, cr, uid, context={}):
        """
        Return  default account period value
        """
        account_period_obj = self.pool.get('account.period')
        ids = account_period_obj.find(cr, uid, context=context)
        period_id = False
        if ids:
            period_id = ids[0]
        return period_id

    def _get_orig(self, cr, uid, inv, ref, context={}):
        """
        Return  default origin value
        """
        nro_ref = ref
        if inv.type == 'out_invoice':
            nro_ref = inv.number
        orig = _('INV:') + (nro_ref or '') + _('- DATE:') + (
            inv.date_invoice or '') + (' TOTAL:' + str(inv.amount_total) or '')
        return orig

    def compute_debit(self, context=None):
        """
        @param cr: the current row, from the database cursor,
        @param uid: the current user’s ID for security checks,
        @param ids: the account invoice refund’s ID or list of IDs

        """
        inv_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
        mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
        act_obj = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
        inv_tax_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.tax')
        inv_line_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
        res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        if context is None:
            context = {}

        for form in self.browse(self):
            created_inv = []
            date = False
            period = False
            description = False
            company = res_users_obj.company_id
            journal_id = self.journal_id
            for inv in inv_obj:
                if inv.state in ['draft', 'proforma2', 'cancel']:
                    raise osv.except_osv(_('Error !'), _(
                        'Can not create a debit note from '
                        'draft/proforma/cancel invoice.'))
                if inv.reconciled and mode in ('cancel', 'modify'):
                    raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'), _(
                        'Cannot %s invoice which is already reconciled, '
                        'invoice should be unreconciled first. You can only '
                        'refund this invoice.') % (mode))
                if form.period.id:
                    period = form.period.id
                else:
                    # Take period from the current date
                    # period = inv.period_id and inv.period_id.id or False
                    period = self._get_period(cr, uid, context)

                if not journal_id:
                    journal_id = inv.journal_id.id

                if form.date:
                    date = form.date
                    if not form.period.id:
                        cr.execute("select name from ir_model_fields \
                                            where model = 'account.period' \
                                            and name = 'company_id'")
                        result_query = cr.fetchone()
                        if result_query:
                            # in multi company mode
                            cr.execute("""select p.id from account_fiscalyear \
                            y, account_period p where y.id=p.fiscalyear_id \
                                and date(%s) between p.date_start AND \
                                p.date_stop and y.company_id = %s limit 1""",
                                       (date, company.id,))
                        else:
                            # in mono company mode
                            cr.execute("""SELECT id
                                    from account_period where date(%s)
                                    between date_start AND  date_stop  \
                                    limit 1 """, (date,))
                        res = cr.fetchone()
                        if res:
                            period = res[0]
                else:
                    date = inv.date_invoice
                if form.description:
                    description = form.description
                else:
                    description = inv.name

                if not period:
                    raise osv.except_osv(_('Insufficient Data!'),
                                         _('No period found on the invoice.'))

                # we get original data of invoice to create a new invoice that
                # is the copy of the original
                invoice = inv_obj.read(cr, uid, [inv.id],
                                       ['name', 'type', 'number', 'reference',
                                        'comment', 'date_due', 'partner_id',
                                        'partner_insite', 'partner_contact',
                                        'partner_ref', 'payment_term',
                                        'account_id', 'currency_id',
                                        'invoice_line', 'tax_line',
                                        'journal_id', 'period_id'],
                                       context=context)
                invoice = invoice[0]
                del invoice['id']
                invoice_lines = inv_line_obj.browse(
                    cr, uid, invoice['invoice_line'], context=context)
                invoice_lines = inv_obj._refund_cleanup_lines(
                    cr, uid, invoice_lines, context=context)
                tax_lines = inv_tax_obj.browse(
                    cr, uid, invoice['tax_line'], context=context)
                tax_lines = inv_obj._refund_cleanup_lines(
                    cr, uid, tax_lines, context=context)
                # Add origin, parent and comment values
                orig = self._get_orig(cr, uid, inv, invoice[
                                      'reference'], context)
                invoice.update({
                    'type': inv.type == 'in_invoice' and 'in_refund' or
                    inv.type == 'out_invoice' and 'out_refund',
                    'date_invoice': date,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'number': False,
                    'invoice_line': invoice_lines,
                    'tax_line': tax_lines,
                    'period_id': period,
                    'parent_id': inv.id,
                    'name': description,
                    'origin': orig,
                    'comment': form['comment']
                })
                # take the id part of the tuple returned for many2one fields
                for field in ('partner_id', 'account_id', 'currency_id',
                              'payment_term', 'journal_id'):
                    invoice[field] = invoice[field] and invoice[field][0]
                # create the new invoice
                inv_id = inv_obj.create(cr, uid, invoice, {})
                # we compute due date
                if inv.payment_term.id:
                    data = inv_obj.onchange_payment_term_date_invoice(
                        cr, uid, [inv_id], inv.payment_term.id, date)
                    if 'value' in data and data['value']:
                        inv_obj.write(cr, uid, [inv_id], data['value'])
                created_inv.append(inv_id)
            # we get the view id
            xml_id = (inv_obj.type == 'out_refund') and 'action_invoice_tree1' or \
                     (inv_obj.type == 'in_refund') and 'action_invoice_tree2' or \
                     (inv_obj.type == 'out_invoice') and 'action_invoice_tree3' or \
                     (inv_obj.type == 'in_invoice') and 'action_invoice_tree4'
            # we get the model
            result = mod_obj.get_object_reference(self,'account', xml_id)
            id = result and result[1] or False
            # we read the act window
            result = act_obj.read(cr, uid, id, context=context)
            # we add the new invoices into domain list
            invoice_domain = eval(result['domain'])
            invoice_domain.append(('id', 'in', created_inv))
            result['domain'] = invoice_domain
            return result

    def invoice_debit(self):
        return self.compute_debit()
```

What I expect is to get the xml id of the view to finally update the invoice that I try to add a debit note from a wizard form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides from what you're trying to do at all, the error is clear. You're calling `get_object_reference()` with 3 arguments, which results in 4 arguments, because it is an instance method and will handle `self` by itself. Just remove `self` in your call.

Comment: When I do what you're suggesting the following error appears:

 raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: account.False